# Securing Rest API in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Can we implement a secured API in `WSO2 ESB` and can we provide an existing user's credential, (as a header) who is in ESB's use store, to access it?
This scenario can be done in ESB Proxy: [Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service) by providing a policy file. Can't we do the same in API too, if not what is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to secure the APIs using Oauth2 you can use [Oauth mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/OAuth+Mediator) but if you looking to use basic auth you  need to write a class mediator(Here is an old [article](http://wso2.com/library/3030/),you can get brief idea on implementing basic auth class mediator even though details are outdated )

Comment: So basically we can't do basic auth for a user in ESB with a policy file for APIs in ESB (which is possible for proxy services), am I right?
Is there a way we can do this by any other method?

Comment: Yes.You can only apply WS security to proxy services(SOAP services).It is not applicable to APIs(REST services).